# Red.xml - It asks me to choose associated class files, When adding jar file by clicking Add Java Library

Tags: robotframework

I'm having a situation to add associated class files of jar that I have chosen rather than adding the jar itself.

Steps Followed:

> 1. Deleted the existing Jar files from RED.xml.
> 2. Clicked 'Add Java Library' and chosen the newly created Jar file of my java project into RED.xml.
> 3. A window opened with all the class files that are associated in the jar file, having asked as "Select the class(es) that defines the
>      library". My Question is why? Am i doing something wrong? It wasn't
>      asked like this before when I used to follow the same steps.
>
>    4. Choosing all the class files displayed in the jar files window. Would the path of these files to be specified in the Robot.suite.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, as this is expected behavior. When you add a single class jar file, then it's easy to assume that this class will be the Robot Library. When you move to a multi-class jar file, that assumption can no longer be made. In order to determine which is the library and which are other (dependency) classes, you have to choose.